# Pass Variable to function in Loadrunner

Tags: c, loadrunner

I have a ParameterArray called `TBname`

```
web_reg_save_param_ex("ParamName=TBname",
        "LB=sysinfo.asp?s=",
        "RB=\" title=\"Systeminformationen",
        "Ordinal=all",
        LAST);
```

Now I want to save the values of `TBname` to a txt file. 
When I compile the program I get the error

> "too many arguments to 'lr_eval_string'"

since the function is expecting only one argument and he thinks that `i` is also an argument. How can I avoid that loadrunner thinks that `i` is an argument?

```
create_report()
{
    int i= 0;


if ((file_stream = fopen(filename, access_mode)) == NULL)  { 
    lr_error_message ("Cannot open or create %s", filename);   
    return -1;
}

for(i=0;i<10;i++){

    TBnameposition = lr_eval_string("{TBname_%d}",i+1);

    fprintf(file_stream,"%s \n",TBnameposition);        
}

fclose(file_stream);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, [`lr_eval_string()`](http://claudihome.com/html/LR/function_reference/Content/c_vuser/lrFr_lr_eval_string.htm) accepts a `const char *`.

You need to make use of [`sprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf) to generate a *string* and then call `lr_eval_string()` with that string.

To elaborate

1. define a `char` array (of enough length), like `char arr[256] = {0}`;
2. use [`sprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf) to put the value in the array, like `sprintf(arr, "{TBname_%d}", i+1);`
3. call `lr_eval_string(arr)`.